# matlab determine curvee

Tags: matlab

i have a plot with many cycles of curves all similar but yet different from each other. the objective is for me to find the mean curve from all this curves. i cannot say where is the beginning or final point from each curve, since each cycle is different.
all i have is an excel file with two columns, one with the x coordinates and the other with the y coordinates.

Any help with be appreciated! thank you very very much!

Comment: Compute the integral and take the mean value ?

Comment: Please don't ask duplicate questions

Comment: Do you have the curve fitting toolbox?

Answer (score 1):

Try to draw plots of different colors. It will be better for perception.

Answer (score 0):

As you still have this in excel you could just build ONE y coordinate vector (median value) and plot this one.